# Error report in var/report ,what does it mean? and is it serious problem? It keep create those error report and take 1.7 GB space already

Tags: magento-1.9, error, reports

Can anyone suggest me how to fix the following error file? It create a lot those error file in `var/report`.

Am I right that I can simply delete all those error file in `Var/report`?

> a:4:{i:0;s:106:"SQLSTATE[42000] [1203] User advancea_mage2 already has
>   more than 'max_user_connections' active connections";i:1;s:3566:"#0
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(109):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #1
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(320):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #2
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460):
>   Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #3
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array) #4
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array) #5
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169):
>   Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8') #6
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql',
>   Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element)) #7
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write') #8
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write') #9
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter() #10
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(360):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter() #11
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection() #12
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
>   13 /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...',
>   Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website)) #14
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/app/Mage.php(491):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...',
>   Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website)) #15
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208):
>   Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...',
>   Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website)) #16
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection() #17
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(608):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection() #18
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores() #19
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store') #20
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/app/Mage.php(684):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) #21
>   /home/advancea/domains/advanceauto.co.th/public_html/index.php(87):
>   Mage::run('', 'store') #22
>   {main}";s:3:"url";s:795:"/our-products.html?amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bp=2&amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bbrand=5&amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bcat=3&amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bmode=list&amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bbrand=19&amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bbrand=18&amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bbrand=4&amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bbrand=18&amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bbrand=19&amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bbrand=8&amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bcar_type=16&amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bp=5&amp%3Bamp%3Bbrand=17&amp%3Bcar_type=16&p=4";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}

Answer (score 2):

You can safely remove `var/report` folder. But those files inside that directory gives you some feedbacks about your application where things going worse.

In this case, it is reporting that you have too many mysql open connection requests. So basically you need to increase the mysql connection count.

***[See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364315/magento-and-database-max-user-connections-error)*** for more details.

Comment: @Kitisak if my answer helped you, feel free to accept my answer :)

Comment: Can you told me how to set those MySQL open connection? this website I hire developer to create for us and I don't have much knowledge about php.

Comment: @Kitisak then you should contact your developer and tell them to do this. Sometime you need server side help in order to accomplish this (depending upon you hosting/server scheme)

Comment: Just read your thread .Thanks @Rajeev K Tomy. Did you mean I have to contact the hosting and they can do something for this issue?

Comment: @Kitisak First you discuss this with your developer. if he cant fix the issue, then most probably it will be a server side issue. But the developer can help you out in this case (at-least he can point out the proper reason)

Comment: Bad luck for me ,I already told him but seem like he ignore my problem. No after-sales service. Maybe he need me to pay extra for fixing this case.